# Using the NOT operator VBA

Tags: vba, boolean

I have a problem which I thought was simple. Not if I'm using `Not` correctly or if I'm missing something else. I want the `If` block to execute if my recordset:

1. has 2 fields
2. at least one field in the ADO recordset has a non-null
   value (If `IsNull` is True for both fields, execute `Else` block)

Otherwise, I need the `Else` block to execute.

```
    If rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2 And _
       Not (IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)) And IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1))) Then

       QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0) & "|" & rSetFlag.Fields(1)
    Else
        QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0)
    End If
```

Am I not getting the right operator precedence? I've tried several other approaches including `Or` in the `IsNull` statement. `Debug.Print` returns the following (don't want the first 2 entries):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `&` symbol is wrong here.
Maybe:
try to check with `rSetFlag.Fields(1).value`
Maybe:
The first 2 entries are here because the values in fields are not `NULL` but `""`so empty string.
you can check it with `Len(Nz(rSetFlag.Fields(1).value, vbNullString)) = 0` if there is no value.
possible solution:

```
If rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2 And _
   Not (Len(Nz(rSetFlag.Fields(0).value, vbNullString)) = 0 _
        And _
        Len(Nz(rSetFlag.Fields(1).value, vbNullString)) = 0) Then

    QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0) & "|" & rSetFlag.Fields(1)
Else
    QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I neglected to mention I was using VBA in Excel. Nz is in the Access Library. [link](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/210161-ado-recordset-undefined-function-nz-expression)

Comment: So its solved now? By using `len(IIF(IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)),"",rSetFlag.Fields(0)))) = 0` ? Or some other way?

Comment: yes, thanks for the help! Though I will say my ADO query returns space and null on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Then let's make it simple.... Use the following:  If still fails, put a breakpoint and inspect values

```
If rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2 Then
    If IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)) And IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1)) Then
        QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0)
    Else
        QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0) & "|" & rSetFlag.Fields(1)
    End If
Else
    QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0)
End If
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still returning `|` with no data on either side.

Comment: I changed the answer to simplify the logic. If still fails, put a breakpoint. Do you have 'Option Explicit' and have you compiled all your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If (rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2) And ((Not IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0))) Or (Not IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1)))) Then

   QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0) & "|" & rSetFlag.Fields(1)
Else
    QueryFlags = rSetFlag.Fields(0)
End If
```

Comment: This returns `|` as well.

Answer (score 0):

When `rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2 And & Not (IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)) And IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1)))` is true? when `rSetFlag.Fields.Count = 2` and `IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)) And IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1))` is FALSE. The second one is false when both are not null. If you want to execute if one of them is at least non-null you have to use `Not (IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0))) or Not(IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1)))` instead of `Not (IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(0)) And IsNull(rSetFlag.Fields(1)))`.

Comment: This doesn't work and I need to evaluate both fields equally. In the above `Debug.Print` image, `Poufs and Accessories|` and `|Exclude` would suffice to execute the `if` block.